# plot_summs: how to remove legends and add a title?

Tags: r

I am sorry if this is a dumb question but I am trying to use jtools:plot_summs in R but I am not really aware of how to edit the resulting plot to:

1. Remove the legend
2. Add a general title on the top
   I am attaching an example of how the package works and the plot it creates

```
library(jtools)
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fit1 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
           Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
fit2 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
           Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
fit3 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
           Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
plot_summs(fit1, fit2, fit3, scale = TRUE)
```

Comment: hi, can you create a reproducible example? without some data to work on is difficult.

Comment: I ama sorry, I edit the question to add the data from the (state.x77) as a example

Comment: looks like there is no way for doing what you need with plot_summs(). maybe try to use ggplot2()

Comment: First I got `Error in `stop_wrap()`:
! Install the ggstance package to use the plot_coefs function.` and then an error about no `broom.mixed` pkg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- p + theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

[image]

Comment: When I djd that I got the following error message: `Error in theme(legend.position = "none") : could not find function "theme"`, but invoking `ggplot2` fixed the error: `p <- p + ggplot2::theme(legend.position="none")`

Comment: Added the needed package load.

Comment: In my defense, I assumed that person attempting to replicate this problem would have already loaded  the `jtools` package and it does import `ggplot2`.